# [Regex]How to get numbers without letter before

Tags: regex

at first I've only discover Regex few days ago...

And I am trying to use Regex to get digits/numbers but only if there is no letters. And even if the letters are before *'**(**'*

---

```
Ex:
```

- *A = 3.2 =>* **3.2**
- *AVariable5 = 3.0 =>* **3.0**
- *vec(0,255)) =>* **0 & 255**
- *vec2(0,0) =>* **0 & 0**

---

Currently I am using the expression [\d.]+ to get digits with the '**.**'
I've tried few things, but no results, always getting more things or nothing.

So I'm asking to you how to do it and with explication if possible.
Thanks to you.

(Sorry if my english is bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d+` is part of the story; what you need is a condition on the prefix, a look-behind, to require that the character before the match is *not* a letter:

```
\b(?<![A-Za-z])\d+([.]\d+)?
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/56aMgf/1)

Comment: Nice. I didn't know [.] was like \.
Just curious, why \b?

Comment: @EricDuminil without `\b` the expression would match `45` in `aa345`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /[^a-z]{1}([\d]+\.{0,1}[\d]{0,})/gmi
```

https://regex101.com/r/nVc1dE/1